# Where does the Splunk Deployment Server store its own checksum data?

Tags: checksum, splunk

This is a great mystery to me.

A Splunk Deployment Server tracks the changes it makes to the Deployment Client by comparing checksums.  You can see in splunkd.log on the client side:

`Checksum mismatch 0 <> 12612942278184057003 for app=myapp`

If there is a mismatch, the Deployment Server decides to send an updated version of its app to the client.  The checksum is then written to $SPLUNK_HOME/var/run/serverclass.xml for later use.

My question is where does the Deployment Server store its own copy? I was expecting there to be a similar xml style file, but I haven't found it yet.

The only place I have seen data related to this is in splunkd.log on the server side, during the creation time of the actual checksum.  This log entry then gets indexed into _internal.

Does this mean the Splunk DS searches _internal to determine if its client is up to date? If so, what happens when the index gets rolled? Does it just re-deploy its apps after it realizes it forgot which clients had which checksum?

Or does the Deployment Server hold this checksum data in memory only?  This doesn't seem so good in the event of an outage, right?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Short answer is that the checksum is stored on the deployment server in a file: `$SPLUNK_HOME/var/run/serverclass.xml`</strike>

There's a comprehensive description of how the checksum mechanism works here:
https://www.hurricanelabs.com/splunk-tutorials/under-the-hood-examining-your-splunk-deployment-server under paragraph *A Word on Checksums*

Comment: That’s not what that section says:  “Based on our testing, the checksum calculated on the deployment server is highly dependent on the timestamps within a given app. “ Serverclass.xml lives only on the client side. Which was demonstrated in the original post. It seems even Hurricane Labs could not conclude exactly how the server checksum worked when they published this article.

Comment: That's right, I've edited my answer. Here's another doc looking at the deployment server - client dialogue
https://www.aplura.com/assets/pdf/conf2014_SanfordOwingsDavidShpritz_SplunkAplura_Deploying.pdf

On the deployment server the individual bundles are located in `$SPLUNK_HOME/var/run/tmp/<<ServerClassName>>/<<appname>>-timestmap.bundle` so although not sure, it may be that the bundle checksum is calculated on the fly